# How to average a column in a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For each rating_id from items_ratings from an item, get the

1. name
2. average of values

My table setup:

item: `id`  `url` `name`

rating: `id`  `name`

items_rating: `id`  `item_id` `rating_id`   `value`

I'm started to solve it with:

```
(Rating.first.id..Rating.last.id).each do |rating_id|
   @item.items_ratings ... 
end
```

but now I seem stuck as `where(rating_id: rating_id)` and `average(:value)` don't work together from here.

input:

`@item.items_ratings.where(rating_id: 1)`

output:

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation
[#<ItemsRating item_id: 5, rating_id: 1, user_id: 1, value: "3">, #<ItemsRating item_id: 5, rating_id: 1, user_id: 1, value: "3">, 
#<ItemsRating item_id: 5, rating_id: 1, user_id: 1, value: "3">, #<ItemsRating item_id: 5, rating_id: 1, user_id: 1, value: "4">, #<ItemsRating item_id: 5, rating_id: 1, user_id: 1, value: "5">]>
```

input:

`@item.items_ratings.where(rating_id: 1).average(:value)`

output:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function avg(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AVG("items_ratings"."value") FROM "items_ratings" WHE...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happened because your 'value' field has a 'string' type. If value will use only as integer, you can change column type to integer or other numeric type, dependency by your database. If you wanna work with string, then if this values will be in integer range, your code can be like: 
`@item.items_ratings.where(rating_id: 1).average('CAST(value AS INT)')`

Answer (score 0):

Argument type for value is a `string`, change that to `integer`

Comment: As you can observe the timestamp, I added my answer directly with the question. Zakhar answered later.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
@item.items_ratings.where(rating_id: 1).average('value')
```